# add modules to a new context in bonfire

Tags: php, codeigniter, module, bonfire

i followed the blog tutorial of Bonfire, i wanted to add the **blog module** to a **new context** called ***News***
i followed the instructions of creating a new context :

1. adding the context
2. localize the context name

**`config/application.php`**

```
    $config['contexts'] = array('content','news','reports','settings','developer');
```

**`language/english/application_lang.php`**

```
    $lang['bf_context_news'] = 'News';
```

---

**My Question Is** : when i type the url `.../index.php/admin/news/blog/` it redirects me to `.../index.php/admin/content/`

Comment: If i would like to add more than one items in main menu without sub menu, How could i do it please can any one help me. I am using latest version of CI-Bonfire.  Suppose under context name 'news' i would love have , sport news, local news , international news as menu items.

Answer (score 2):

i found the answer,
in fact, to create a **context** you have to do 3 things :

1. adding the context : config/application.php;
2. localize the context name : application_lang.php;
3. adding the route : **application/config/routes** : line 73

   ```
   Route::context('yourContextName');
   ```